# How can I use the data in the selected rows in GridView and show that list on another page?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a web site in Visual Studio, something like an on-line library. I have a GridView on the first page that presents all of the books available from the data source and some other properties also contained in the data source. The GridView contains check boxes and the user can choose which books he wants to order by checking a box. My question is how can I use the data in the selected rows, the list of books with their properties and show that list on another page, so that the user is able to know which items he has selected?

I tried with a for loop on the FirstPage:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int bookID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[i][0];
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    purchaseProductList.Add(bookID);
                    Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx?bookID" + i + "=" + bookID); 
                }
       }
```

and then on the SecondPage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["bookID" + i] != null)
    {
        DataRow row;
        row = dtBooks.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = Request.QueryString["bookID" + i];
        dtBooks.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
GridView1.DataSource = dtBooks;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

but it didn't work. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes I do. I did what the other commenter suggested and I get an error


Source Error:


Line 81: &nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></p>
Line 82:     <p>
Line 83:         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Line 84:             DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="LibrarySqlDataSource" 
Line 85:             ViewStateMode="Enabled" AllowPaging="True" Width="485px" CellPadding="4" 

Do you have any comments on this maybe?

Comment: The information you provide in the comment should go to another question. Link to this question so others can follow what is going on and what got you to the point you are at now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use session to keep selected ids

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int bookID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[i][0];
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    purchaseProductList.Add(bookID);
                    ids.Add(bookID);
                }
       }

Session["Ids"] = ids;

Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx");
```

from second page you can access session and load those ids to grid

```
var list = (List<string>)Session["Ids"];

foreach (string id in list)
{

  DataRow row;
  row = dtBooks.NewRow();
  row["ID"] = Request.QueryString["bookID" + id];
  dtBooks.Rows.Add(row);
}
GridView1.DataSource = dtBooks;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, i get an error message:

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 

Do you know maybe, what else should I change?